# ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, npm-link

I'm using Angular 6.0.7. I'm trying to debug one of my packages locally. For that I'm using `npm link`. But when I try to serve the application it throws an error,

> ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.

Following are the steps I followed to link my package

1. `npm link` on my package folder
2. `npm link my-package` on my application folder
3. In ts-config file of my application I included my package as `"include": ["./node_modules/my-package"]`

And on the angular.json file `"preserveSymlinks": true`.
Before linking the package locally the application works perfectly.
Am I missing something here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: look at this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by doing some changes to the tsconfig file. Hope this helps someone whose having a similar issue.
I had to include the `.ts` files in my tsconfig like below,

```
"include": [
   "**/*.ts",
   "./node_modules/my-package"
 ]
```